# How can i get all categories Id selected by Root Category

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have three root category, i need all categories id for only selected root categories how can i get it. what are all the possible way to get it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $categoryId = 2;?>
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) ?>
<?php $_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>

<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php if($_category->hasChildren()):?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></a>
                                <?php $_category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                                <?php if($_category2->hasChildren()):?>
                                <?php $_subcategories2 = $_category2->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php foreach($_subcategories2 as $_subcategory2): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory2) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory2->getName() ?></a>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Try this

Comment: could you pls explain brief

Comment: FYI : https://snag.gy/6LdTjV.jpg

Comment: I have use 2 which is Default Root Category (ID: 2), You can use according to your root Category

Comment: FYI : snag.gy/6LdTjV.jpg – zus here you can use id:30 and it will show the sub categories associated with id 30

Comment: Is my code right : https://justpaste.it/1g4bi

Comment: "Is my code right : justpaste.it/1g4bi  "~~~yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72146/discussion-between-zus-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: error https://snag.gy/8Pj6ng.jpg

Comment: sorry, a bit busy now.. the code which i have given will work

Comment: require_once  '/app/Mage.php'; try using this

Comment: As you know , using  
require_once '/app/Mage.php'; getting error : https://snag.gy/xEtLAm.jpg

Comment: Partially working,  https://justpaste.it/1g4c8

Comment: <?php
require_once '/app/Mage.php';
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(30);
foreach ($children as $category) {
    echo $category->getId();
}
?>

Comment: But i need all tree level category id, now its return main category id's only, i need child category and grandchild category id also.

Comment: sorry to say your suggestion code not working, the working code is : https://justpaste.it/1g4c8

Comment: updated the answer, its working code

Comment: Almost i reached the solution, only thing is how can i get also children category ids and grandchildren category ids.  Now the output like return only main category id only.

Comment: try the code,which i have updated..it will return all the trees based on the id

Comment: error : https://snag.gy/8Pj6ng.jpg

Comment: use   require_once 'app/Mage.php';     it is showing error b'z Mage.php file path is not found, its a basic, you can fix the basic things

Comment: Yes, the mistake is mine, i am newbie for code, could you pls help where i can add  
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Comment: at the top of file, if you using file externally

Comment: Its working, but how can i get id instead of category name like your starting code.  Output : https://snag.gy/Gvxj7u.jpg

Comment: after the change ->getName()  code : https://justpaste.it/1g4f7  output : https://snag.gy/bahvpz.jpg

Comment: Final Code: https://justpaste.it/1g4h1 output: https://snag.gy/uN9K4E.jpg  Thank You @Rahul

Comment: cheers mate (y)

Comment: In my live site i have two stores, how can i add store selection in this code : https://justpaste.it/1g4h1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72318/discussion-between-zus-and-rahul-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. It's very simple.

```
     <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

function convert_to_csv($input_array) {
    /** open raw memory as file, no need for temp files */
    $today = date('Ymd');
    $file_path = "var/catgory_ids" . $today . ".csv";
    $temp_memory_backup = fopen($file_path, 'w');
    fwrite($temp_memory_backup, $input_array);
    fclose($temp_memory_backup);
    echo 'Data saved to csvfile.csv';
}

$catid = 2;

$sub_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid)->getChildrenCategories()->getAllIds();

$data = array();
$headers = array();

$header['cat_id'] = 1;

foreach ($sub_categories as $i => $category) {
    $data[$i]['cat_id'] = $category;
}

$tmp_columns = array();
foreach ($header as $head => $v) {
    $tmp_columns[] = $head;
}
$output.= implode(",", $tmp_columns) . "\n";

//building rows
foreach ($data as $rows) {
    $output.= implode(",", $rows) . "\n";
}

// Send the CSV file to the browser for download
convert_to_csv($output);
?>
```

Comment: where will the output save?

Comment: just print_r($sub_categories) you will get all ids.

Comment: is possible to download as CSV file in output folder.

Comment: yes. now I have updated the code.

Comment: now the output look like : 234567 how can i separate 2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: wait. I will update code.

Comment: I have updated the export code. You can possible to run this code in root folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72151/discussion-between-stalinrajindian-and-zus).